# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object This Error comes in that Function

Tags: laravel-7

```
public function productTrackOrder(Request $request)
{
$order=Order::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->where('order_number',$request->order_number)->first();
```

Comment: `auth()->user()->id`; are you logged in? `auth()->user()` will be `null` if you're not, and you can't call `(null)->id`.

Comment: Always try to make your question the best readable possible using: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1):

You can access the user id via the Auth facade.

```
Auth::id()
```

However, always do a check to be share that the user is logged in to avoid a non object-error

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

// can always check if the user is logged in before running your query

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $order=Order::where('user_id',Auth::id())- 
    >where('order_number',$request->order_number)->first();
}
```